# How to get data via Webhook? (GoCardless)

Tags: php, httprequest, webhooks

I'm testing using Webhooks for the first time. I want to set up a Webhook (using GoCardless.com, but this shouldn't matter now).

I'm in the sandbox and I have set up a Webhook there:

```
{
  "id": "WE000012RYRQ9E",
  "created_at": "2017-03-01T18:03:34.252Z",
  "enabled": true,
  "secret": "qpILcgnnAWznkuJcajXYvMNsQcrkKwDzL6KHMq5z",
  "name": "TestHook",
  "url": "https://example.com/webhook.php",
  "client_cert_details": null,
  "links": {}
}
```

Then I'm trying to send a Webhook to my `webhook.php` having this code:

```
 <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$result = $_REQUEST['events'];
$obj = json_decode($result, true);

print_r($_GET);
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_REQUEST);
print_r($result);
print_r($obj);
```

You can see the result here:

[image]

So, I assumed that I'll get the data with `$_REQUEST['events']` like displayed, but at the bottom you can see that I only get empty arrays back.

Is this something about the secret key (`qpILcgnnAWznkuJcajXYvMNsQcrkKwDzL6KHMq5z`)?

I don't know how to set this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webhook data is sent to your server as JSON in the body of the request. In PHP, you'll need to access this with `file_get_contents('php://input')`.

Once you've got the body, you can decode it into an array, and then work with the data however you want:

```
$raw_payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
$payload = json_decode($raw_payload, true);

// Each webhook may contain multiple events to handle, batched together
foreach ($payload["events"] as $event) {
    // Do something with the event here
    print("Processing event " . $event["id"] . "\n");
}
```

For a full guide on handling webhooks, see GoCardless's [getting started guide](https://developer.gocardless.com/getting-started/api/staying-up-to-date-with-webhooks/?lang=php#building-a-webhook-handler). That also shows you how to use the secret key to make sure a webhook really comes from GoCardless, and isn't being spoofed.

You've included your webhook secret in this post, so you'll want to reset that now, otherwise someone could send you fake webhooks pretending to be GoCardless. You can do that in your [sandbox GoCardless dashboard](https://manage-sandbox.gocardless.com) by clicking "Developer" on the left-hand side, then clicking on your endpoint, then clicking "Edit".

Comment: Thank you. I remember to overlooked some docs as I asked this question and got my problem solved back then. I didn't use a real webhook secret in this post, but nice to know.

Answer (score 0):

I just found an example after searching a lot. Maybe this helps someone else. Note that most code seems to be deprecated but you'll know that when you've studied the uptodate [GoCardless API](https://developer.gocardless.com/getting-started/developer-tools/test-webhooks/):

https://github.com/gocardless/gocardless-legacy-php/blob/master/examples/webhooks.php

Comment: This link points at the legacy PHP docs. Are you using the legacy API, or the current "pro" API?